# What part of the code should I edit in order to remove this image in my wordpress site?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

It has been about 1-2 months since the image has appeared. I believe I tried to add a google analytics tag or the advertisements by google adsense using a plug-in. I do not remember what I touched and when that caused the problem. I am absolutely clueless with each element of wordpress: (e.g. header-one.php, header-two.php, theme.php, and etc.). Does anyone have an idea how to fix it?

The image below is my webpage:
[image]

The second image is what should not be in the webpage which was shown above:
[image]

Solution Attempt# 1:
[image]

Did not work if I did it correctly.

Comment: so you want to remove this image from shop page only or from all the pages

Comment: It's from all the pages, it should not be there at all

Comment: also want to remove title too?

Comment: Basically, the second image (the image with the man) pushed down my content down. The menu bar and the content should have no gap in between. So the image of the man and the word should be removed

Comment: may be there is a setting in your wordpress admin where you can disable this section but  you can also use css to hide this section . put this css in your style.css

Comment: #content .page_header_wrap, .woocommerce .entry-header{     display: none;  }

Comment: Alright will do. I'm absolutely clueless about CSS do I just paste it at the bottom of the page?

Comment: if page template is used in all the pages then you can add this in page  or i will suggest to add this in style.css or may be in header in case if you want hide the image section from all the pages

Comment: wrap it inside style tag :

Comment: <style> 
#content .page_header_wrap, .woocommerce .entry-header{ display: none; }</style>

Comment: Please refer to my main post. I edited it to include your solution. I'm not sure if I did it correctly because it did not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is simple. It´s a theme setting. Just go to your Customizer settings and select breadcrumb settings. There you can change the default image or simply disable the breadcrumb section.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot the image is disappeared after Disabling `WooCommerce Archive Page`